# KSH: Loop performance

Tags: performance, loops, ksh

I need to process a file with approximately 120k lines that has the following format using ksh:

```
"[UserId=USER1]";"Client=001";"Locked_Status=0";"TYPE=A";"Last_Logon=00000000";"Valid_To=99991231";"Password_Change=20120131";"Last_Password_Change=29990" 
"[UserId=USER2]";"Client=000";"Locked_Status=0";"TYPE=A";"Last_Logon=20141020";"Valid_To=00000000";"Password_Change=20140620";"Last_Password_Change=9501"
"[UserId=USER3]";"Client=002";"Locked_Status=0";"TYPE=A";"Last_Logon=00000000";"Valid_To=99991231";"Password_Change=20140304";"Last_Password_Change=9817"
```

The output should be something like:

```
[UserId=USER1] Client=001
Locked_Status=0
TYPE=A
Last_Logon=00000000
Valid_To=99991231
Password_Change=20120131
Last_Password_Change=29985
[UserId=USER2]
Client=000
Locked_Status=0
TYPE=A
Last_Logon=20141020
Valid_To=00000000
Password_Change=20140620
Last_Password_Change=9496
[UserId=User3]
Client=002
Locked_Status=0
TYPE=A
Last_Logon=00000000
Valid_To=99991231
Password_Change=20140304
Last_Password_Change=9812
```

I initially used the following code do process the file:

```
for a in $(<$1)
do
        a=$(echo $a|sed -e 's/;/ /g' -e 's/"//g')
        for b in $a
        do
                print $b
        done
done
```

It was taking around 3hrs to process 120k lines.
Then I tried to improved the code changing it to the following:

```
   for a in $(<$1)
   do
     printf "\n$(echo $a|sed -e 's/"//g' -e 's/;/\\n/g')"
   done
```

That gave me 2hrs processing time however it still takes too long to process 120k lines

At last I tried this code which processed the 120k lines in 3secs!

```
  perl -ne '
            chomp;
            s/\"//g;
            s/;/\n/g;
            print;
           ' <$1
```

Is there anyway I can improve the code in KSH to achieve similar performance? I believe that I must be missing something in my KSH code... Help me to find out please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
tr ';' '\n' < file | tr -d '"'
```

Your code is assigning **every whitespace-delimited word** to variable "a" in turn, and thus invoking `sed` once for each word in the file. Clearly a lot of accumulated overhead spawning all those processes. The idiom to iterate over the *lines* of a file is:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do ...; done < file
```

Comment: Hi Glenn,
The code you gave me had the best results
Thanks you very much

`Host> wc -l /tmp/MyTest`
`  114449 /tmp/MyTest`


`Host> time tr ';' '\n' < /tmp/MyTest | tr -d '"' > /tmp/zuza.out`

`real    0m1.04s`
`user    0m1.06s`
`sys     0m0.08s`

`Host> time perl -ne '`
`                     chomp;`
`                     s/\"//g;`
`                     s/;/\n/g;`
`                     print "\n$_";`
`                    ' </tmp/MyTest > /tmp/zuza`

`real    0m1.30s`
`user    0m0.60s`
`sys     0m0.08s`

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting. I having a bad time to put my comment in the way I want

Comment: <blink>
    Host> wc -l /tmp/MyTest
      114449 /tmp/MyTest
    
    
    Host> time tr ';' '\n' < /tmp/MyTest | tr -d '"' > /tmp/zuza.out
    
    real    0m1.04s
    user    0m1.06s
    sys     0m0.08s
    
    Host> time perl -ne '
                         chomp;
                         s/\"//g;
                         s/;/\n/g;
                         print "\n$_";
                        ' </tmp/MyTest > /tmp/zuza
    
    real    0m1.30s
    user    0m0.60s
    sys     0m0.08s
</blink>

Comment: Very tricky to get comment formatting nice, especially if you have backticks. I had a hunch that piping tr to tr might be faster even than perl (which is usually a performance monster for text processing)

Answer (score 0):

You suggestion worked perfectly

```
Host> wc -l /tmp/MyTest
  114449 /tmp/MyTest


Host> time tr ';' '\n' < /tmp/MyTest | tr -d '"' > /tmp/zuza.out

real    0m1.04s
user    0m1.06s
sys     0m0.08s

Host> time perl -ne '
                     chomp;
                     s/\"//g;
                     s/;/\n/g;
                     print "\n$_";
                    ' </tmp/MyTest > /tmp/zuza

real    0m1.30s
user    0m0.60s
sys     0m0.08s
```

Comment: The answer of Dan is a reply to the answer of @Glenn.
Dan is completely happy, ksh turns out to be faster than perl. Dan, you can accept Glenn's answer now.